# C# Compiler Switch for TargetFrameworkVersion

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

im trying to compile an assembly at runtime with CSharpCodeProvider and i would like to know which compiler switch to use to target for example .NET Framework 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> options = new Dictionary<string,string>
{ 
    {"CompilerVersion", "v2.0"}
};

var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(options);
```

Comment: It kinda works but how do i check if it is really is on 2.0 base ?

Comment: @Chilln - What do you mean it kind of works? What about it isn't working?

Comment: No the thing is just, im abit confused, if i just use the C# Compiler v2.0 or target the Framework v2.0 or is this the same?

Comment: @Chilln - Setting `CompilerVersion` does indeed target the `v2.0 Framework`